# Bash single command, update command output

Tags: bash, replace, find

I get following value from "command1" I need to update this UTC StartDATE and EndDate to ETS in single command. How do I do it.

```
$>command1
{
    "Jobs": [
        {
            "StartDATE": 1601283799.807,
            "State": "COMPLETED",
            "JobId": "abc123",
            "EndDate": 1601272679.289,

        },
                {
                "StartDATE": 1600211301.064,
                "State": "COMPLETED",
                "JobId": "abc1234",
                "EndDate": 1600211282.846
        },
}
```

I know I can convert UCT using "date -d @". But how do I update and print in the same line. I need the output like below.

```
$>command1|command....
{
    "Jobs": [
        {
            "StartDATE": Mon Sep 28 05:03:19 EDT 2020,
            "State": "COMPLETED",
            "JobId": "abc123",
            "EndDate": Mon Sep 28 05:57:59 EDT 2020,

        },
                {
                "StartDATE": Tue Sep 15 19:08:21 EDT 2020,
                "State": "COMPLETED",
                "JobId": "abc1234",
                "EndDate": Tue Sep 15 19:19:02 EDT 2020
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `perl` for the purpose: you can use `localtime` to convert the captured epoch time to human-readable. notice `e` at the end of the search and replace block.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$ENV{TZ} = "America/New_York"}; s/([\d.]+)/localtime $1/e if /StartDATE|EndDate/'
{
    "Jobs": [
        {
            "StartDATE": Mon Sep 28 05:03:19 2020,
            "State": "COMPLETED",
            "JobId": "abc123",
            "EndDate": Mon Sep 28 01:57:59 2020,

        },
                {
                "StartDATE": Tue Sep 15 19:08:21 2020,
                "State": "COMPLETED",
                "JobId": "abc1234",
                "EndDate": Tue Sep 15 19:08:02 2020
        },
}
```